# Removing a line from HTML Pogramatically through Open2

Tags: perl, pdf-generation, cgi

I have a code that shows up in two different places, one is a browser html page, then the other is a downloaded PDF.  On this page there is a line that says "print using the print button" but of course that isn't on the PDF model so I would like to remove it when the function printFilePdf is run.  However I can't add (or I don't know how) a condition do the HTML that is in the method.

```
sub printHeader {
my ($outFH) = @_;

my ($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $month, $year) = (localtime)[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$month++;
$year += 1900;

my ($string) = scalar localtime(time());

print $outFH <<EOT;

<html>
<head>
    <title>THIS IS A TITLE</title>
</head>
<body>
<table width="640" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="bold">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="bold">
            <div align="center" class="header">
                I want to keep this line $string<br>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="bold">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="bold" style="color: red; text-align: center">
            I also what to keep this line.
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="bold" style="color: red; text-align: center">
            This line is not needed when the printFilePdf function is run.
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

   EOT

    print $outFH qq(<p align="center">&nbsp; </p>);

    print $outFH <<EOT;
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

EOT

}
```

Is there anyway to do this? Like add a name to the table row and in the method above say something like

```
if(!printFilePdf())
{
<tr>
    <td class="bold" style="color: red; text-align: center">
        This line is not needed when the printFilePdf function is run.
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Comment: Is this related to your previous question? (You never responded on it...). If so, and you are using that answer, you could probably handle it through CSS. Please advise on both questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just break the HTML into two parts: one is common to both the formats, one is HTML specific:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

sub printHeader {
    my ($outFH, $goes_to_html) = @_;

    print $outFH <<'__HTML__';
Here is the common text.
__HTML__

    print $outFH <<'__HTML__' if $goes_to_html;
This doesn't go to PDF.
__HTML__

}

print "To HTML:\n";
printHeader(*STDOUT, 1);

print "To PDF:\n";
printHeader(*STDOUT, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the caller. If caller is `printFilePdf` then search and replace to delete unneeded data.

```
perldoc -f caller
```

---

As a side note: If you are using some templating engine like [HTML::Template](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Template) then it'd be lot easier. In that case you can put conditionals in HTML.

```
<TMPL_IF NAME="NON_PDF">
  Some text that only gets displayed if NON_PDF is true!
</TMPL_IF>
```